# Error 0x80005000 using windows prompt to create a user in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

So I have the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
string[] serverNameParts = ServerName.Split('.');
string CN1 = t1.Text, CN2 = "Users";
string pwd = t2.Text;
startInfo.Arguments = "/c dsadd user " + "CN=" + CN1 + ",CN=" + CN2 +",";

for (int i = 0; i < serverNameParts.Length; i++)
{
    startInfo.Arguments = startInfo.Arguments + "DC=" + serverNameParts[i] + ",";
}
startInfo.Arguments = startInfo.Arguments + " & ping www.google.com /t";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I used ping so I could see why it won't create an account.
What I get is this error:
Error code = 0x80005000
type dsadd /? for help.

I can't figure out what could be the problem here, I checked the final string and it looks totally fine and I even typed it into the promt and everything worked perfectly, but it won't when I use it in my app. Is there any way to solve this? I suppose it has something to do with the permissions, but I can't come up with an idea to give my program the rights to run an administrator cmd.

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggested?  "type dsadd /? for help"?  Have you googled the error code or error message?

Comment: Yes I have, typing the command didn't give any relevant information, neither did googling the error code.  People had similar error, but in different situations, and their solutions don't help me, unfortunately.